# Why does the CassandraRDD compute method execute a bunch of token range searches?

Tags: cassandra, driver, apache-spark, datastax

So I was wondering (and can't figure out through looking at the code) exactly why the datastax cassandra driver does a bunch of token range searches.

For example,
http://pastebin.com/3gux40vU

The code that we use is

```
rdd.select("bucket").collect().foreach(println)
```

It happens for any select that we do, regardless of whether or not we call collect(). The table drop_me_soon is a temporary table with the schema bucket int PRIMARY KEY. It has one single entry of 0. In particular, it *seems* like the code

```
val rowIterator = tokenRanges.iterator.flatMap(fetchTokenRange(session, _))
```

Causes it to do all of the token range searches, but I could be wrong. Could anyone here shed some light?

Answer (score 1):

The Spark driver performs a full scan over the complete token range. It queries the `system.peers` table to get the host vs set of token ranges to get the location and replica placement. It then maps Cassandra’s token ranges and Spark’s partitions. This is a many-one mapping in case of v-nodes and one-one otherwise.

It then schedules the computation of each partition by doing a token range query on the available workers according to the above computed mapping. For each replica, it prefers the worker running on the replica itself.

In your case, Cassandra really does not know how many rows there are in all the nodes. If you are using a single Cassandra node, then you have v-nodes which split the token range in 256 splits. So it will always try to scan over all the token range splits to get the result.

Comment: Welcome to SO, trulite